# Rails & MySQL: SELECT Statement Single vs. Double Quotes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, quotes

I have a CRON job which executes a SELECT statement to grab records.  When the SELECT runs on my dev machine, it produces the following statement:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 87 LIMIT 1
```

This is successful.

When the SELECT runs on my production (hosted) machine it produces the statement with double quotes:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users”.”id” = 87 LIMIT 1
```

This is not successful and I get a MySQL 1064 error,

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.* FROM "users" WHERE "users
```

The code is the same on both machines, but my dev MySQL is version 5.5.33, whereas production is 5.1.67 (I don't have control over this to set/update it)

Is there a way to force single quotes or another preferred method to handle this situation?

Thanks for your time and assistance.

**--EDIT--**

Here are the main code snippets that are invoked via my CRON job:

/lib/tasks/reports.rake

```
namespace :report do
  desc "Send Daily Report"
  task :daily => :environment do
    User.where(:report_daily => 1).find_each do |user|
      ReportsMailer.send_report(user, 'daily').deliver
    end
  end
```

/app/mailers/reports_mailer.rb

```
def send_report(user, date_increment)
   @user = user
   @date_increment = date_increment
   get_times(user)
   mail :to => user.email, :subject=> "Report: #{@dates}"
 end
```

**--EDIT2--**

So it looks like I need to use slanted single quotes (`) in order for this to work successfully.  How do I force my app or MySQL to use these instead of double (") quotes?

Comment: What method are you using to run this query? Have you tried downgrading your dev MySQL version, to confirm this also happens locally?

Comment: I've added method snippets into my edit above.  Thanks!

Comment: I have not attempted a downgrade, but will try.

Comment: Please review Edit 2. Thanks!

Comment: You need to show us the code that constructs the SQL.  Also, how are you determining the SQL that is executed on each machine (e.g. from the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html))?  If you are guessing then it is worth noting that, as documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html), "If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks".

Comment: The code is in the first Edit above. RoR constructs the query. The SQL is taken from my local terminal and from the log files on the hosted server.  I don't have control over server settings on the hosted box. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with RoR, so I may be missing something... but how does the code that you have posted generate the SQL about which we're talking?  In particular, from where does the predicate `users.id = 87` come?

Comment: User is a model (table) within my application.  RoR knows what database fields comprise this table, so I can simply say user.id, user.name, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further inspection, and working with my hosting company, its turns out that my query is timing out on their server.  Thanks to all that responded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *why* it does this, but I do know that if you're referencing column names in MYSQL, you need to use ``, whereas values / data should be wrapped in "", like this:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = "87" LIMIT 1
```

I learnt this the hard way back in the day when I was learning how to do simple MYSQL queries

Here's some documentation from [MYSQL's site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) for you:

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
```

> Identifier quote characters can be included within an identifier if
>   you quote the identifier. If the character to be included within the
>   identifier is the same as that used to quote the identifier itself,
>   then you need to double the character. The following statement creates
>   a table named a`b that contains a column named c"d:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `a``b` (`c"d` INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you couldn't put some of your sql statement directly into your code like:

```
User.where("`report_daily`=1").find_each do |user|
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any literals, the format of the generated SQL statements should be determined by the underlying adapter. Perhaps you have a different mysql adapter installed or configured on each machine. Check the installed version. For example:

```
bundle show mysql
```

and also check the adapter configuration for your project in database.yml. For example:

```
adapter: mysql
```

A comparison of the results of these checks between each machine should tell you if you are using different adapters on the two machines.